# How to ask for LOCATION PERMISSION in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing a simple app that show your current position ( latitude and longitude). I am using the functions:

```
- navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
- navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
```

But I have noticed that the permission is granted without asking for permission at the user.

Is this agaist the google's rules?

If yes, how can I show a dialog that ask for the permission?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions). Make sure, you make use of `location` instead of `photo` and everything else should be straightforward.

Comment: Which platform do you refer to, `android` or `ios`?

Comment: @PritishVaidya Android :)

Comment: If you don't want to use an external library, you can try [geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation#requestauthorization), which comes with React-Native, I tried this but got stuck at some point don't remember lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the android [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

> Android apps must request permission to access sensitive user data (such as contacts and SMS), as well as certain system features (such as camera and internet)
>
> If the device is running **Android 6.0 (API level 23)** or higher, and the app's **targetSdkVersion is 23** or higher, the user isn't notified of any app permissions at install time. Your app must ask the user to grant the **dangerous permissions at runtime**.
>
> If the device is running **Android 5.1.1 (API level 22)** or lower, or the app's **targetSdkVersion is 22** or lower while running on any version of Android, the system **automatically** asks the user to grant all **dangerous permissions for your app at install-time**.

To grant the Permissions manually you must use **PermissionsAndroid** before each request which is well mentioned in this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid)

```
try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                   'so you can take awesome pictures.'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera")
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
```

The list of **dangerous permissions** are mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups)

Answer (score 4):

For android, You can use PermissionAndroid by importing from 'react-native'.

import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native'; //

Checkout this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid) for more info.

For iOS, You have to fill the .plist file and it pops for permission. No need to handle it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be looking at doing this with the react-native-permissions

```
Permissions.request('location', { type: 'always' }).then(response => {
  this.setState({ locationPermission: response })
})
```